# What if I need synchronicity for users to have a chance to respond to output before giving input?

Tags: node.js

Imagine implementing an fdupes sort of scenario in Node.js.  It seems impossible.  What are people's suggestions for this?

Take the 'prompt' module on npm.  This is roughly what my code looks like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  log('shit up console with lots of messy and space-consuming output, pushing everything else off the screen.');
  prompt.get('foo', function(err, resp){
    doSomethingWith(resp.foo);
  });
}
```

Before the user could even have time to enter their first response, 50 more sets of output have crowded the information that they would need to make a decision about their second response off of the screen.

This seems like a major fail of node's too-hip-for synchronicity gimmick, does it not? Am I missing something?

Comment: check out [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which might come in handy for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather another case where you can't (always) apply the same kind of coding pattern that you'd use when programming in a strictly synchronous language.

One way to solve the problem in Node:

```
function showPrompt( i ) {
    log('fill console with lots of messy and space-consuming output, pushing everything else off the screen.');
    prompt.get('foo', function(err, resp) {
        doSomethingWith(resp.foo);
        if( i < 50 ) {
            showPrompt( i + 1 );
        }
    });
}

showPrompt( 0 );
```

Comment: Will I not exhaust the callstack's size limit this way for too many iterations?  This caveat doesn't exist with a simple forloop.  Is this not a downside? What advantage does forcing me to go along with the hipster bullshit against my will present in this case?

Comment: The stack is quite large, you'd have to have way more iterations to exhaust it. The advantage is that it makes the program work the way you inted it. If you're so strongly opposed to how Node works, it might be a wise move to use some other programming language instead.

Comment: Way to dodge the question.  "If you don't like it leave" is fine, i guess, if you want to have a shitty product, but it doesn't produce positive dialog.

Comment: There actually are some solutions to your problem that won't make the stack explode. Create a queue using mbostock's [queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) module, set the `parallelism` option to 1 (ie. no parallelism) and it should stay tail recursive.

Comment: How is that dodging the question? If you have an asynchronous function, this is how you work with it. It's not meaningful to discuss the advantages of working code over non-working code. If you're asking why the method is asynchronous in the first place or why use asynchronous methods at all, that's another discussion.

Comment: the question was "how does the design of node which rams this model down my throat present any advantage?"

Comment: not, "what other workarounds are there to the pain in the ass it caused by trying to be buzzword compliant"?

Comment: In *this particular example* there's no advantage, but this is not the use case Node was designed for, either.

Comment: @Juhana fair enough, that's an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to loop over some asynchronous functions, you should try using async's [`timesSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#timesseriesn-callback), which applies a function to n times in series. If any function returns an error, a main error handler will be called.

Here is an example, using your code:

```
var async = require('async');
async.timesSeries(50, function (n, next) {
  prompt.get('foo', function  (err, res) {
    var value = doSomethingWith(resp.foo);
    if (value !== 'bar') next(new Error('value !== bar'));
    else next(null, value); 
  }
}, function (err, res) {
  // err !== null
  // or res is an array with 50 elements
});
```